# Assign Tracking Number and Flag it

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 tables

Table 1

```
Customer Name , Order id , Tracking Id 
sailesh , 23546 , NULL
nilesh , 26362 , NULL
```

Table 2

```
Tracking id , Used
RN167367 , No
RN47282 , NO
```

I want assign a tracking number in table 1 for each order and then mark it as used.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not use `SEQUENCE/computed column that depends on IDENTITY`?

Comment: the tracking number is assigned by  Logistic provider cant use Sequence

Comment: How do you want to assign the tracking id to order number? Should order `23546`  get `RN167367` or `RN47282`?

Comment: Order 23546 should get RN167367 and 26362 should get RN47282

Comment: Does you table 2 has identity column/creation date or something like that? Without it it how do you want to get the correct order?

Comment: Tracking no are unique and we need to assign one number to each order who has currently Trackingno as NULL

Comment: there is no sequence in assigning you can assign first number to first record.

Comment: Hey lad2025 waiting for answer...

Comment: No explicit order in second table so you can't get result like first -first, second - second. Simple without `ORDER BY` the order is not guaranteed .

Comment: we just need to assign tracking number ... sequence is not importanat... but only one tracking number to each order ...

Comment: after we have used that tracking number we will flag it in Used as yes .. so we dont use that number again

Answer (score 0):

First assign tracking numbers and then mark them:

```
;with cte1 as(select *, row_number() over(order by orderid) rn
              from table1 where trackingid is null),
      cte2 as(select *, row_number() over(order by trackingid) rn 
              from table2 where Used = 'NO')
 update c1 set trackingid = c2.trackingid
 from cte1 c1
 join cte2 c2 on c1.rn = c2.rn


 update t2 set Used = 'YES'
 from table1 t1
 join table2 t2 on t1.trackingid = t2.trackingid
```

Comment: ;with cte1 as(select *, convert(varchar(50),row_number() over(order by leadid)) rn
              from [Demo].[dbo].[Dispatches_Temp] where trackingno is null),
      cte2 as(select *, convert(varbinary(50),row_number() over(order by trackingno)) rn 
              from [Demo].[dbo].[TrackingId] where Usedflag = 'NO')
 update c1 set trackingno = c2.trackingno
 from cte1 c1
 join cte2 c2 on c1.rn = c2.rn


 update t2 set Usedflag = 'YES'
 from [Demo].[dbo].[Dispatches_Temp] t1
 join [Demo].[dbo].[TrackingId] t2 on t1.trackingno = t2.trackingno

Comment: error Implicit conversion from data type varchar to varbinary is not allowed

Comment: ;with cte1 as(select * , row_number() over(order by leadid) rn
              from [Demo].[dbo].[Dispatches_Temp] where trackingno is null),
      cte2 as(select *, row_number() over(order by trackingno) rn 
              from [Demo].[dbo].[TrackingId] where Usedflag = 'NO')
 update c1 set trackingno = c2.trackingno
 from cte1 c1
 join cte2 c2 on c1.rn = c2.rn


 update t2 set Usedflag = 'YES'
 from [Demo].[dbo].[Dispatches_Temp] t1
 join [Demo].[dbo].[TrackingId] t2 on t1.trackingno = t2.trackingno

Comment: error after using this : Implicit conversion from data type varchar to varbinary is not allowed

Comment: What is datatype of Tracking Id  in both tables? What is datatype of Used ?

Comment: Oh sorry.. it was varbinary by mistake in tracking number.... have changed it and now it is successful .. Thanks Giorgi